# Removing legend in ggscatter from ggpubr

Tags: r, ggpubr

I want to make R value and p value in scatter plot in different color and want to put it high position.
However, when I tired to change the color, there is weird legend on the top.
Is there anyone who knows how to delete the legend on the top and move R value and p value to higher position?

This is the code that I used

```
sp<-ggscatter(Density,x="Vessel.number",y="Sum",add="reg.line",conf.int = TRUE,cor.coef =TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",xlab = "The number of vessel", ylab = "Density(items/m^2)",yscale="log10")

sp+stat_cor(aes(color="#3399FF"))
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any data so, I am using `iris` data

```
library(ggpubr)
sp<-ggscatter(iris, x="Sepal.Length",y="Petal.Length",add="reg.line",
                  conf.int = TRUE, 
                  xlab = "The number of vessel", ylab = "Density(items/m^2)",
                  yscale="log10")
    
    
sp + stat_cor(aes(color="#3399FF"), show.legend = FALSE, label.y = 1)
```

[image]

It is better to remove `cor.coef =TRUE, cor.method = "pearson"` part from `ggscatter` as you are proving it again through `stat_cor` function. You can change the `label.y` value to change the position of R value and p value suitably.